# Css selector .a.b how do i exclude it from selecting a.b.c?

Tags: html, css

I have inherited some markup very similar to the html below.

```
<div class="a b">how_can_i_select_ab_only</div> 
<div class="a b disabled">how_can_i_select_ab_and_disabled_only</div>
```

I want to select both elements individually.

css selector **.a.b** selects both divs

- `<div class="a b">how_can_i_select_ab_only</div>`
- `<div class="a b disabled">how_can_i_select_ab_and_disabled_only</div>`

What is the selector to select only class **a.b.disabled** and only class **a.b** ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Three ways how to do it:

The first one, set styles to `.a.b` and them remove them (override) for `.a.b.disabled`.

```
.a.b {color: red;}
.a.b.disabled {color: grey}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/p84s61gp/

The second way, use the `attr` selector.

```
[class='a b'] {color: red}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/p84s61gp/1/

Next, you can use `:not` selector, but support since IE9.

```
.a.b:not(.disabled) {color: red}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/p84s61gp/2/

Comment: I went for the simplest option of just setting it and then immediately overriding it (option 1).

Answer (score 3):

The `:not()` selector will help:

```css
.a.b:not(.disabled) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="a b">how_can_i_select_ab_only</div> 
<div class="a b disabled">how_can_i_select_ab_and_disabled_only</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `:not()` css selector.

`.a.b:not(.disabled)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

this should target div with class a AND disabled

```
.a.disabled {}
```

this should target div with class a AND b

```
.a.b {}
```